# Finding the effective accessibility of fields and types in a Roslyn analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing a Roslyn analyzer to enforce some documentation rules. The rules states that only fields and types visible outside the assembly needs to be documented. This leads me to the problem of finding out whether a field or type is effectively visible and can be used outside the declaring assembly.

Given this declaration:

```
namespace TestApp {
    internal class InternalClass {
        public class InnerClass {
            public int PublicFieldInInternal;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know whether `PublicFieldInInternal` is visible outside the declaring assembly. I use the code below to determine the accessibility:

```
private bool IsNonPrivateMemberDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, SyntaxNode node)
{
    if (node is BaseFieldDeclarationSyntax fieldDeclaration)
    {
        var firstField = fieldDeclaration.Declaration.Variables.First();
        var fieldAccessibility = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(firstField).DeclaredAccessibility;

        return ConstructVisibleFromOtherAssemblies(fieldAccessibility);
    }

    var accessibility = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(node)?.DeclaredAccessibility;
    if (accessibility != null)
    {
        return ConstructVisibleFromOtherAssemblies(accessibility.Value);
    }

    Debug.Assert(true, "This code should be unreachable as one of the two cases above will catch all calls");
    return false;
}

private static bool ConstructVisibleFromOtherAssemblies(Accessibility accessibility) =>
    accessibility == Accessibility.Public ||
    accessibility == Accessibility.Protected ||
    accessibility == Accessibility.ProtectedOrInternal;
```

However, it does not take the accessibility of parent types into consideration, so the `DeclaredAccessibility` property for the symbol corresponding to `PublicFieldInInternal` returns `Accessibility.Public`. Is there a way to query the semantic model directly to get the effective accessibility, or do I need to recursively look at containing types?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you have to recursively look at the containing types. See [`IsMemberAccessible`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Semantics/AccessCheck.cs,239cf446e6b53c8c). They check `IsNamedTypeAccessible` on the containing type.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with this approach, and it passes all unit tests:

```
private bool IsVisibleFromOtherAssemblies(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, SyntaxNode node)
{
    ISymbol declaredSymbol = GetDeclaredSymbol(context, node);

    var accessibility = declaredSymbol.DeclaredAccessibility;
    var visibility = ConstructVisibleFromOtherAssemblies(accessibility);
    var containingType = declaredSymbol.ContainingType;

    return IsSymbolAndContainingTypeVisible(visibility, containingType);
}

private static ISymbol GetDeclaredSymbol(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, SyntaxNode node)
{
    if (node is BaseFieldDeclarationSyntax fieldDeclaration)
    {
        var firstField = fieldDeclaration.Declaration.Variables.First();
        return context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(firstField);
    }

    return context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(node);
}

private bool IsSymbolAndContainingTypeVisible(bool visibility, INamedTypeSymbol containingType)
{
    if (containingType == null)
    {
        return visibility;
    }

    return visibility && IsSymbolAndContainingTypeVisible(
               ConstructVisibleFromOtherAssemblies(containingType.DeclaredAccessibility),
               containingType.ContainingType);
}

private static bool ConstructVisibleFromOtherAssemblies(Accessibility accessibility) =>
    accessibility == Accessibility.Public ||
    accessibility == Accessibility.Protected ||
    accessibility == Accessibility.ProtectedOrInternal;
```